# Как сделать двигающиеся полосы на чистом css

Tags: javascript, html, css, scss

Появилась задача сделать полосы вокруг кнопки

[image: скрин кнопки которую нужно сделать]

Делал на Code Pen через ::before , ::after и в них делал box-shadow, но ничего не получилось

```css
.container {
  font-size: 40px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 20px;
  &:hover {
    background-color: #ff4e50;
    color: #fff;
  }
}

.container::after {
  box-shadow: 3px 3px red
}
```

```html
<button class="container">Contact</button>
```

Answer (score 4):

Для того что бы `:before` и `:after` отображались, у них нужно задавать свойство `content`.

```css
body {
  background: black;
}

button {
  color: white;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;

  position: relative;

  line-height: 250%;
}

button:before,
button:after {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  content: "";
  width: 15px;

  height: 3px;
  background: red;

  transition-duration: 0.7s;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
}

button:before {
  left: calc(100% - 15px);
}
button:after {
  right: calc(100% - 15px);
}

button:hover:before {
  left: 0;
}
button:hover:after {
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<button>contact</button>
```

Comment: `left` и `right` стоит заменить на `translateX`

Comment: А по какой причине?

Comment: @Ein, ибо на обработку `translate` тратится меньше ресурсов.

Answer (score 4):

Хм.. Вариант с использованием `linear-gradient`

```css
.effect {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 0;
  --color: red; /* Цвет */
  background:
    linear-gradient(to left, var(--color), var(--color)),
    linear-gradient(to left, var(--color), var(--color));
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: top left, bottom right;
  background-size: 20% 3px; /* ширина и высота */
  transition: all .3s linear;
}

.effect:hover {
  background-position: top right, bottom left;
}
```

```html
<div class="effect">Hover me</div>
```